# CKEditor error: Attempted import error: 'ckeditor4-react' does not contain a default export (imported as 'CKEditor')

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I am trying to use the CKEditor in my react app. I don't know why this error is occurring.

This is how I've imported the CKEditor:

`import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-react';`

This is how I've used it:

```
<CKEditor 
    onChange={evt => console.log( evt )}
/>
```

This is the error I keep getting:

`Attempted import error: 'ckeditor4-react' does not contain a default export (imported as 'CKEditor').`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write
*import {CKEditor} from 'ckeditor4-react';*
because of default export you should use **{}**

Comment: It's not correct. See this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/vv50789765?file=/demo.js:326-334

Comment: @davoodSandoghsaz, yea the official website says it should be just `CKEditor` too, but it worked when I used the `{}`

Comment: it's Good but weird @Eliza

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having this issue - for us it was because with `ckeditor4-react < 2.0.0`, there was no native TypeScript support, so we introduced our own `index.d.ts` types file. After upgrading however, our file was no longer compatible. We simply removed our `index.d.ts` types file, updated some of the props (e.g. we were using `data` instead of `initData`) and everything worked after that.